# List view not getting populated by array adapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am new to android and have been following udacity's video lectures.
The list view is not getting populated by the array adapter and when
i ran the app on mobile the app showed only the main activity layout.

the list view is not appearing on the mobile screen ,can anyone tell me  whats the error here,is it something related to frame layout or is there an 
error in
 array adapter.
 Thanks in advance

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
public static class PlaceHolderFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
    public PlaceHolderFragment(){}
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View rootview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        String[] forecastArray={
                "Today","Tommorow","wed","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"
        };//creating some fake data to show in list view
        List<String> fore=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
        mForecastAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_forecast,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,fore);
        ListView listview= (ListView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listview.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
        return rootview;

    }
}
}
```

**activity_main_xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/container"
tools:context="com.saxenarc.jeetesh.layouts.MainActivity">
</FrameLayout>
```

**list_item_forecast.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
>

</TextView>
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listview_forecast"></ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Checked everything thrice before posting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code and list is working well but you haven't told the list where to be displayed. You can fix this in 2 ways.

---

**First**

Add the fragment inside the main activity since its not visible.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new PlaceHolderFragment).commit();
    }
```

---

**Second**

Stop using the fragment and use the listview inside the Main activity

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listview_forecast"></ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
List<String> fore = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item_forecast,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,fore);
ListView listview= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
listview.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
```

Comment: @JeeteshSaxena `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();` Please mark it as the correct answer if you found it helpful